# Jenkins: Differing behaviour when running script - rake command gives rake aborted!\ncannot load such file -- bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, jenkins, rake, robotframework

Below is the full content of a script i have that i try to run in Jenkins. The rake command gives an error of

```
rake aborted!\ncannot load such file -- bundler/setup\n/var/www/sponsor1_integration/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'\n/var/www/sponsor1_integration/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'\n/var/www/sponsor1_integration/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'\n(See full trace by running task with --trace)")
```

Im not sure why this is. If i log onto server directly and run the command, it executes

```
Starting process_patient_data_feed.
Finished process_patient_data_feed.
```

Here is the code. Is there something environmental i need to do to get this to behave properly via jenkins.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/www/sponsor1_integration/processed/
sudo rm -rf /var/www/sponsor1_integration/failed/
sudo rm -rf /var/www/sponsor1_integration/to_process
sudo mkdir /var/www/sponsor1_integration/processed/
sudo mkdir /var/www/sponsor1_integration/failed/
sudo mkdir /var/www/sponsor1_integration/to_process
sudo mv /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/study-3277_LONGBOAT_20170112_12:37.csv /var/www/sponsor1_integration/to_process
cat /var/www/sponsor1_integration/to_process/study-3277_LONGBOAT_20170112_12:37.csv
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/sponsor1_integration/to_process/study-3277_LONGBOAT_20170112_12:37.csv
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/sponsor1_integration/processed/
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/sponsor1_integration/failed/
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/sponsor1_integration/to_process
cd /var/www/sponsor1_integration/
rake RAILS_ENV=production longboat:process_patient_data_feed_01        search_folder=to_process processed_folder=processed failed_folder=failed
cd /var/www/sponsor1_integration/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test script under Jenkins credentials. By default Jenkins user login is jenkins.

Check if bundler gem is installed and available to Jenkins user.

Also take a look here: [Jenkins Rake Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rake+Plugin), [Jenkins RVM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RVM+Plugin)

Comment: good hint, I would suggest to check file/folder ownership and file permissions for owner and other users. Note that you may have different user running on Jenkins (master) and nodes

Comment: @jozefow thank you, checking permissions is a must. OR just sudo to appropriate user (lazy one is root).

Comment: Am i doing this right?      root@jenkins-s4 rfrancis]# bundle check
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Comment: @user3303266 I see root user here, you need to switch user to appropriate one like jenkins. Try `su jenkins` and if there no shell for that user, just change it: `chsh /bin/bash jenkins` and then again `su jenkins`.